# Class loses "this" scope when calling prototype functions by reference

Tags: javascript, function, reference, scope, prototype

Can anyone explain to me why "b" returns undefined and how I can get around this problem? Why does the "this" scope get lost when I call prototype functions by reference?

```
MyClass = function(test) {
this.test = test;
}

MyClass.prototype.myfunc = function() {       
   return this.test;
}

var a = new MyClass('asd').myfunc();
var b = new MyClass('asd').myfunc;

// Returns "asd" correctly
console.log(a)

// Returns undefined??
console.log(b())
```

*=== EDIT / SOLUTION ===*

As plalx writes, the correct solution in my case is to use .bind(). So the result looks like this:

```
MyClass = function(test) {
    this.test = test;
}

MyClass.prototype.myfunc = function() {       
   return this.test;
}

var a = new MyClass('asd').myfunc();
var b = new MyClass('asd'),
    bfunc = b.myfunc.bind(b)

// Returns "asd" correctly
console.log(a)

// Also returns "asd" correctly!
console.log(bfunc())
```

Comment: That's how `this` works.  It's set when you _call_ the function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitely bind the this value if you want this behaviour.

```
var c = new MyClass('asd'),
    b = c.myfunc.bind(c);


console.log(b());
```

By default, `this` will point to the `leftSide.ofTheDot();` in an invocation, or simply **the object on which the function was called**.

*Note: Calling `b();` is the same as `window.b();`.*

Binding every function to the object instance is possible but rather inefficient because functions will not get shared across instances anymore.

E.g.

```
function MyClass(someVal) {
    var me = this;

    me.someVal = someVal;

    me.someFn = function () {
        return me.someVal;
    };
}
```

Comment: Any way to bind it right at the myfunc definition so that it's always bound this way?

Comment: @EvgueniNaverniouk Yes, I updated the answer, however I would not recommend it, unless you have very specific needs. Why do you need this?

Comment: Right, so that's exactly what I want to avoid. I want to define the function as part of the prototype to ensure it's shared correctly, however, I also want to ensure I can call those functions by reference as described in my original answer. Sounds like it's not possible.

Comment: @EvgueniNaverniouk, Well in that case I would simply use `bind` when you need to store a function reference. You could also store an object like `var ref = {fn: theFunction, thisArg: theObject}` and later use `ref.fn.call(theObject)`.

Answer (score -1):

The line `var b..`. is a function reference and you're not actually calling the function.

Comment: That's exactly what he's trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, that confused me at first - but when you look down at his console log statement, he's calling b() there, after having retrieved the function from the object.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are assigning to **a variable** a result of myfunc() function.

```
var a = new MyClass('asd').myfunc();
```

And here, you are asigning to b variable function reference, rather then runing it, and assign result to variable.

```
var b = new MyClass('asd').myfunc;
```

And finaly here:

```
console.log(b())
```

You trying to log result of **function b** and in that case b() isn't defined anywhere, only it is assigned reference to function.

Try this:

```
console.log(b); // It logs [Function]
```

But besides that, your question is hard to understand.

P.S. Use semicolons!