# Emit event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, emit

My emit event just don't want to fire. I am new at nodejs, sorry for dumb mistake, but I can't solve it for a few hours.

**client module**

```
var Client = require('steam');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var newClient = function(user, pass){
    EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.userName = user;
    this.password = pass;

    var newClient = new Client();
    newClient.on('loggedOn', function() {
        console.log('Logged in.'); // this work
        this.emit('iConnected'); // this don't work
    });

    newClient.on('loggedOff', function() {
        console.log('Disconnected.'); // this work
        this.emit('iDisconnected'); // this don't work
    });

    newClient.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error'); // this work
        this.emit('iError'); // this don't work
    });
}
require('util').inherits(newClient, EventEmitter);

module.exports = newClient;
```

**app.js**

```
var client = new newClient('login', 'pass');

client.on('iConnected', function(){
    console.log('iConnected'); // i can't see this event
});

client.on('iError', function(e){
    console.log('iError'); // i can't see this event
});
```

Comment: from where comes "client" module? at var Client = require('client');

Comment: This module works. I mean his events (loggedOn, loggedOff, error) works. So now i want to transmit them further.

Comment: it's hard to test what you are doing, because i'm not really understand what is , but  i can see two things here, try to not use the same  name of newClient inside the constructor when you make  "var newClient = new Client();"  and probably you loose the this scope inside the event listeners functions.  may be this can  help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457294/class-loses-this-scope-when-calling-prototype-functions-by-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **this** keyword  lose the scope of "newClient" object , you should make something like.

```
var self = this;
```

and then, call inside the listeners as

```
newClient.on('loggedOn', function() {
    console.log('Logged in.');
    self.emit('iConnected'); // change this to self
});
```

In order to make it works.

Take a look to this link [Class loses "this" scope when calling prototype functions by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457294/class-loses-this-scope-when-calling-prototype-functions-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

It was a scope problem. Now all work's fine.

```
var newClient = function(user, pass){
    EventEmitter.call(this);

    var self = this; // this help's me

    this.userName = user;
    this.password = pass;

    var newClient = new Client();
    newClient.on('loggedOn', function() {
        console.log('Logged in.');
        self.emit('iConnected'); // change this to self
    });

    newClient.on('loggedOff', function() {
        console.log('Disconnected.');
        self.emit('iDisconnected'); // change this to self
    });

    newClient.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error');
        self.emit('iError'); // change this to self
    });
}
require('util').inherits(newClient, EventEmitter);

module.exports = newClient;
```